# Excel Automatically Open Dropdown List with Focus / NumLock issue

Tags: vba, excel, sendkeys, validation

I have a group of cells in my worksheet that use a data validation list. It works great, but I'd like the list to dropdown automatically when one of these cells gets the focus. I found some code online to make this work.

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetSelectionChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)
   If Target.Worksheet.Name = "Sheet1" And Target.Column = 1 Then
       Application.SendKeys ("%{down}")
   End If
End Sub
```

Courtesy of: http://howoffice.com/automatically-open-the-drop-down-list-when-a-cell-get-focus-in-excel/

However, the issue I'm having is with the `SendKeys` causing the NumLock to toggle on and off. I looked this up and it's a known issue with the command.

Are there any other alternatives to the SendKey command to accomplish what I'm looking to do here?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

This code works for me:

Courtesy of: [On focus after tabbing of Excel drop down, automatically show list for selection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6525462/on-focus-after-tabbing-of-excel-drop-down-automatically-show-list-for-selection)

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range


    On Error GoTo Err1:

    If Target = Range("I5") Then
        Application.SendKeys ("%{UP}")
    End If

    If Target = Range("I6") Then
        Application.SendKeys ("%{UP}")
    End If

    If Target = Range("I7") Then
        Application.SendKeys ("%{UP}")
    End If

Err1:
    'do nothing
End Sub
```

And here's the code with SDB MadDog's corrections:

If you want it to apply to all cell's with data validation
( '[On focus after tabbing of Excel drop down, automatically show list for selection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6525462/on-focus-after-tabbing-of-excel-drop-down-automatically-show-list-for-selection) )

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)




    On Error GoTo Err1:
If Target.Cells.Count = 1 Then

        If Target.Validation.InCellDropdown = True Then
        Application.SendKeys ("%{UP}")

        End If
End If


Err1:
    'do nothing
End Sub
```

However, it changes my NUMLOCK status (toogle ON / off) everytime!
He mentioned he fixed it with an API, I tried, but it doesn't work because it can't get numlock status read correctly (this one http://www.freevbcode.com/ShowCode.asp?ID=1151)

But hope this helps someone in need!

Answer (score 0):

this code works for me :

```
    SendKeys "%{down}", True
    DoEvents
    SendKeys "{SCROLLLOCK}"
```