# Click a Pull-Down with VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I have a small macro that establishes a Data Validation pull-down in cell **B2**

```
Sub InternalString()
    Range("B2").Select
    With Selection.Validation
        .Delete
        .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:= _
        xlBetween, Formula1:="alpha,beta,gamma,delta"
        .IgnoreBlank = True
        .InCellDropdown = True
        .InputTitle = ""
        .ErrorTitle = ""
        .InputMessage = ""
        .ErrorMessage = ""
        .ShowInput = True
        .ShowError = True
    End With
End Sub
```

The macro also **Select**s the cell.  I would like to add something to the macro that would "click" on the pull-down, so that once control is returned to the user, they would see:

[image]

Any suggestion are welcome.

Comment: There is something similar-ish [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6525462/on-focus-after-tabbing-of-excel-drop-down-automatically-show-list-for-selection).

Comment: Following that suggestion, `Application.SendKeys ("%{DOWN}")` seems to do the trick.

Comment: @DavidZemens  You are correct!! ........create an Answer and I'll mark this *Answered* .........thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modifying from the suggestion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6525462/on-focus-after-tabbing-of-excel-drop-down-automatically-show-list-for-selection), it seems like `SendKeys` should do the trick:

```
Sub InternalString()
    Range("B2").Select
    With Selection.Validation
        .Delete
        .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:= _
        xlBetween, Formula1:="alpha,beta,gamma,delta"
        .IgnoreBlank = True
        .InCellDropdown = True
        .InputTitle = ""
        .ErrorTitle = ""
        .InputMessage = ""
        .ErrorMessage = ""
        .ShowInput = True
        .ShowError = True
    End With

    '"Show" the validation list as a dropdown:
    Application.SendKeys ("%{DOWN}")
End Sub
```