# Auto expansion of drop-list in merged cells in excel

Tags: excel, vba

I have some merged cells with data validation drop down lists I tried the following method to make them automatically expand when on focus it applies on single cells, but when I tried to apply on merged cells, writing their range it doesn't work.

[On focus after tabbing of Excel drop down, automatically show list for selection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6525462/on-focus-after-tabbing-of-excel-drop-down-automatically-show-list-for-selection)

first code

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
On Error GoTo Err1:

If Target = Range("d10") Then
    Application.SendKeys ("%{UP}")
End If Err1:
'do nothing     End Sub
```

[it worked perfectly][1]

when I merged cells it doesn't work, even I tried to change range to all merged cell it doesn't work either.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
On Error GoTo Err1:

If Target = Range("d10:n10") Then
    Application.SendKeys ("%{UP}")
End If   Err1: 'do nothing    End Sub
```

Any idea how make it work?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What's your code? If you don't show your code, how do you expect to get help for it?

Comment: code in the link:                                                                                            
  Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    On Error GoTo Err1:

    If Target = Range("A1") Then
        Application.SendKeys ("%{UP}")
    End If

    If Target = Range("B1") Then
        Application.SendKeys ("%{UP}")
    End If

    If Target = Range("C1") Then
        Application.SendKeys ("%{UP}")
    End If

Err1:
    'do nothing
End Sub

Comment: a screenshot of your setup would help.

Comment: done............

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Merged cells lead to all kinds of problems and should be avoided. You could use

```
If Target.Address = "$A$1:$C$3" Then
```

or better yet

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
If Not Intersect(Target, Range("A1")) Is Nothing Then
    MsgBox "merged cells are bad for your health"
End If

End Sub
```

[image]